# Node with Vue, different ports for requests and API

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, routes, port

I have a project that is based on node and has Vue as a front-end.

In my app.js file in node I have

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
    //static folder
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public'))); 
    //handle SPA
    app.get(/.*/, (req, res)=>{
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
    });
}
```

and then

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log('Server runs on port ', port);
});
```

So, node listens on port 4000 and all incoming requests (from port 4000) go to `'/public/index.html'` to get served by vue

In my `vue.config.js` I have

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    outputDir : path.resolve(__dirname, '..public'),
    devServer:{
        proxy:{
            '/*':{
                target:'http://localhost:5000'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine for now, but please help me understand the following

How can I have node listening to a port (eg 80) and then all other node api endpoints in another port (eg 4000) ?

I want all incoming requests to go to port 80, then still go to `'/public/index.html'`, so Vue can take over.

But , the node endpoints Vue uses to GET and POST data , I want them to still be in port 4000, `const basicUrl = 'http://awesomeness:4000/';`

How can I do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may need to create 2 express App as shown in the link below :

[NodeJS Express - separate routes on two ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28755281/nodejs-express-separate-routes-on-two-ports)

The first one will listen to port 80 and will return the index.html file.

The other one will listen to 4000 and handle request from your Vue app.

Comment: Thats a good idea, come to think of it, but how about one http server with two ports? Can node do that somehow?

Comment: it seems like a servr can only listen to one port so you have to create new server (basic node js)/app (expressJs) everytime you want to handle a different port. Yet you can create them in the same file. So you can have one nodeJs script that can handle multiple port throught different "servers"/"app".